# React forwardRef HoC not giving reference to container element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I am trying to build a generic HOC for a closing element on click of outside its space(generic close on outside solution).

As I see it ,this could be achieved with forwardRef and HOC implementation and although there is an example in official docs I cannot seem to get it right.

So I want my HOC to create a reference to the container of component. It is wrapping because it has handlers to track clicks and act upon them. For instance, lets say we have a generic Dropdown component, one would expect that I can close it on any click outside the area of this component.

The code I currently have:

```
import React from 'react';

function withClose(Component) {
 class ClickContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClose);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClose);
    }

    handleClose(e) {
      // I expect having here context of container of wrapped component to do something like
      const { forwardedRef } = this.props; // <- I expect having context in forwardedRef variable
    }

    render() {
      const { forwardedRef, ...rest } = this.props;
      return <Component ref={forwardedRef} {...rest} />;
    }
  }

  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <ClickContainer {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />;
  });
}

export default withClose;
```

What am I missing here? I cannot make it work, I only get context of wrapped component not the element itself.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What is `this.containerRef`? You need to pass `this.props.forwardedRef` to element

Comment: @Orar yeah sorry this was just something left behind what I've tried, I changed it to proper code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ref should be passed down to the element

Checkout https://codesandbox.io/s/7yzoqm747x

Assuming

```
export const Popup = (props,) => {
  const { name, forwardRef } = props;
  return (
   <div ref={forwardRef}>  // You need to pass it down from props
     {name}
   </div>
  )
}
```

And the HOC

```
export function withClose(Component) {
  class ClickContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
     super();
     this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClose);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClose);
    }

    handleClose(e) { 
     const { forwardRef } = this.props;
     console.log(forwardRef);
    }

    render() {
      const { forwardRef, ...rest } = this.props;
      return <Component forwardRef={forwardRef} {...rest} />;
    }
  }

  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <ClickContainer {...props} forwardRef={ref} />;
  });
}
```

And expect

```
 const CloseablePopup = withClose(Popup);

  class App extends Component {
    popupRef = React.createRef();
    render() {
      return (<CloseablePopup ref={popupRef} name="Closable Popup" />);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Basically this is correct solution, I was missing creating ref in container... Although this does not answer my question entirely. Do you know is it possible to implement it without providing the ref from parent? This requires me to define refs on multiple places instead of just leaving it to HOC to handle everything by itself. Thanks

Comment: HOC passing ref without it being handled by wrapped component can result in an error if the wrapped component is a function. If wrapped component is a class, the ref can only access the instance of the class and not the container element. Read here https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs

Answer (score 1):

I Implemented the same thing few days ago.
I wanted a HOC that handle `onClickoutside`

I wanted that component to check on each click if the child was click or not and if it did to invoke a function on the child.

this was my solution:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function withClickOutside(WrappedComponent) {
  class WithClickOutside extends WrappedComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);
      this.wrappedElement = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside, true);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside, true);
    }


    handleClickOutside(event) {
       if (event.type !== 'click') return;
       if (!this.wrappedElement.current) {
          throw new Error(`No ref for element ${WrappedComponent.name}. Please create ref when using withClickOutside`);
        }

      if (!this.wrappedElement.current.contains(event.target)) {
         if (!this.onClickOutside) {
           throw new Error(`${WrappedComponent.name} does not implement onClickOutside function. Please create onClickOutside function when using withClickOutside`);
         }

       this.onClickOutside(event);
     }
   }


   render() {
     const wrapped = super.render();
     const element = React.cloneElement(
       wrapped,
       { ref: this.wrappedElement },
     );

     return element;
   }
 }

 return WithClickOutside;
}
```

Then the component you wrap must implement a function called `onClickOutside` .

Comment: This is one solution, it works but it is a bit hackish. I would like to implement it without cloneElement if it possible in anyway. Can you think of any other solution for the implementation?

Comment: I know its abit hack but for some reason taking this solution and trying to make it work without the clone element and getting to ref to the wrapped component did not worked.

Whats good is that you dont need to handle with refs in the wrapped component so you save some code and bugs that you forget to add it